# Python events per second

Tags: python, scheduling

I am attempting to write a script to send information to a remote syslog server.  I would like to throttle to x number of events per second.  With the following code I have been able to get about 10k per second but in all reality for some tests this may be a bit slow.  When I attempt to go any faster it it does not seem to be able to catch up.  I immagine it has something to do with the large amount of call I want to do but I am using next to no ram for the process and only 30% of a single core.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import argparse, socket, sched, time

### constants ###
SYSLOG_PORT = 514
MESSAGE = "Hello World!"

### Setup Scheduler ###
scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def newTimedCall(callsPerSecond, callback, *args, **kw):
    period = 1.0 / callsPerSecond
    def reload():
        callback(*args, **kw)
        scheduler.enter(period, 0, reload, ())
    scheduler.enter(period, 0, reload, ())

### argument reading ###
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-t', '--target', help='Target IP', required='True')
parser.add_argument('-e', '--eps', help='Events Per Second', required='True')
args = parser.parse_args()
eps = float(args.eps)
targetIp = args.target

### setup socket
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

def sendMessage():
    socket.sendto(MESSAGE, (targetIp, SYSLOG_PORT))


newTimedCall(eps, sendMessage)
scheduler.run()
```

So my question gets down to, what can I do alternatively to achieve a larger rate?  It seems I am attacking this from the wrong standpoint.  Doing a simple while true loop I can send at 60-70k eps. On a single thread/core.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I would like to send `n` number of messages in a second and I would like to run that until I stop.  The example show hello world but it will be changed to be the specific message I am looking for.